# How can I get the string result of a python method from the XML-RPC client in Java

Tags: java, python, xml-rpc

I wrote:

```
Object result = (Object)client.execute("method",params);
```

in java client.

Actually, the result should be printed in string format. But I can only output the address of "Object result", how can I get the content?

And I have tried String result = (String)client.execute("method",params);

It says lang.until.Object can not cast to lang.util.String.

As the server is written in Python, I was wondering how can I retrieve String from the method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hesitant to post this because it seems rather obvious - forgive me if you've tried this, but how about:

```
String result = (String)client.execute("method",params);
```

Answer (score 0):

so maybe the object returned is not a string... are you sure that you're returning a string in your python application? I seriously doubt it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python. Like,
scored_candidates = map(lambda x:(x[0],x[1],sum(map(lambda y:y[2],x[1]))),candidates.items())
what should be the corresponding return type of "scored_candidates "

Comment: I figured out those objects in Python are type of dictionary, so what's the corresponding type of Python dictionary in Java?

Comment: I did lots of research... change it to Hashtable and HashMap. None of them works. I am now beginning to change all the code in Python to Java.